# Meteor slingshot access defind issue on sarafi browser

Tags: meteor, amazon-s3, safari, meteor-slingshot

everyone,
i have some issue about access defind when i use safari-web-browser. another web-browser had notting issue when upload and download from AWS S3, but only have issue when use safari, anybody hava some idea about this? just, let me know your solution, plz..

update,

i realized that occasion when used other languages. if use English fileName was ok, but when use other language, i got error msg.

Comment: Please post the full (exact) error message you're seeing.

Comment: @hwillson actually, i got error code like this <Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)> when load image and then <Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden)> this error code when i tried upload to AWS S3. it's very strange cuz i got this error code when use Sarafi.. other brower was notting problems.. any idea?